# ListView with CustomArrayAdapter showing everything empty

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

I want to use a custom layout for the ListView Items, I created my XML, have my custom object and created the custom ArrayAdapter, passed the adapter but everything shows empty

no clue of errors on LogCat

I believe the problem is in the `ArrayAdapter` Class, here's my code

```
public class EntityListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EntityInfo> {

    Context context;
    List<EntityInfo> _entities;
    int layoutResID;

    public EntityListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceID,
                             List<EntityInfo> listItems) {
        super(context, layoutResourceID, listItems);
        this.context = context;
        this._entities = listItems;
        this.layoutResID = layoutResourceID;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        EntityHolder entity;
        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(layoutResID, parent, false);
            //LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //view = inflater.inflate(layoutResID, parent,false);
        }// else {
        //    entity = (EntityHolder) view.getTag();
        //}
        entity = new EntityHolder();
        entity.mEntityName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_entity_name);
        entity.mEntityType = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_entity_type);
        entity.mImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_icon);

        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        EntityInfo _entity = (EntityInfo) this._entities.get(position);

        entity.mEntityName.setText(_entity.getEntityName());
        EntityTypeInfo _entityType = db.getEntityType(_entity.getEntityTypeId());
        entity.mEntityType.setText(_entityType.getEntityTypeName());
        //Uri uri = Uri.parse(_entity.getImageUri());
        //entity.mImage.setImageURI(uri);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return _entities.size();
    }

    private static class EntityHolder {
        TextView mEntityName;
        TextView mEntityType;
        ImageView mImage;
    }
}
```

So this is where I set the adapter to the ListView

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_entities, container, false);

        TabHost tabs = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        tabs.setup();

        TabHost.TabSpec peopleTab = tabs.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.entities_tab_people));
        peopleTab.setContent(R.id.People);
        peopleTab.setIndicator(getString(R.string.entities_tab_people));
        tabs.addTab(peopleTab);

        // Home
        TabHost.TabSpec banksTab = tabs.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.entities_tab_banks));
        banksTab.setContent(R.id.Banks);
        banksTab.setIndicator(getString(R.string.entities_tab_banks));
        tabs.addTab(banksTab);

        // Home
        TabHost.TabSpec governmentTab = tabs.newTabSpec(getString(R.string.entities_tab_gov));
        governmentTab.setContent(R.id.Taxes);
        governmentTab.setIndicator(getString(R.string.entities_tab_gov));
        tabs.addTab(governmentTab);

        tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(new AnimatedTabHostListener(tabs));

        TabWidget widget = tabs.getTabWidget();
        for (int i = 0; i < widget.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View v = widget.getChildAt(i);

            // Look for the title view to ensure this is an indicator and not a divider.
            TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
            if (tv == null) {
                continue;
            }
            v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_indicator_ab_money);
        }

        DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());
        List<EntityInfo> _entities = db.getAllEntities();
        List<EntityInfo> _banks = new ArrayList<EntityInfo>();
        List<EntityInfo> _people = new ArrayList<EntityInfo>();
        List<EntityInfo> _gov = new ArrayList<EntityInfo>();

        for (EntityInfo _entity : _entities) {
            if (_entity.getEntityTypeId() == 2) {
                _people.add(_entity);
            } else if (_entity.getEntityTypeId() == 3) {
                _banks.add(_entity);
            } else if (_entity.getEntityTypeId() == 4) {
                _gov.add(_entity);
            }
        }

        if (_people.size() > 0) {
            ListView _listPeople = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_person_entities);
            EntityListAdapter _peopleAdapter = new EntityListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.entity_list_item, _people);
            _listPeople.setAdapter(_peopleAdapter);
        }
        if (_banks.size()>0) {
            ListView _listBanks = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_bank_entities);
            EntityListAdapter _banksAdapter = new EntityListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.entity_list_item, _banks);
            _listBanks.setAdapter(_banksAdapter);
        }
        if (_gov.size() > 0) {
            ListView _listGov = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_gov_entities);
            EntityListAdapter _govAdapter = new EntityListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.entity_list_item, _gov);
            _listGov.setAdapter(_govAdapter);
        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

If I comment the ImageView, I can see the sample image that I have set, but if I uncomment it, nothing is shown.

Here's the XML layout for the list item

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="75dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <ImageView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/list_icon"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_action_picture"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txt_entity_name"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/txt_entity_type"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's the layout of the fragment where I show this list item (where I'm getting everything empty

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.andujardev.money.EntitiesFragment">

    <TabHost
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/People"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@color/lighter_gray">

                    <ListView
                        android:id="@+id/list_person_entities"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:divider="@color/light_gray"
                        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                        android:choiceMode="none"
                        />

                    </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Banks"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:background="@color/lighter_gray">
                    <ListView
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/list_bank_entities"
                        android:divider="@color/light_gray"
                        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                        android:choiceMode="none">

                    </ListView>
                    </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/Taxes"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:background="@color/lighter_gray">
                    <ListView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/list_gov_entities"
                        android:divider="@color/light_gray"
                        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                        android:choiceMode="none">

                    </ListView>
                    </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>

</FrameLayout>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/770/create-custom-listview-in-android/

Comment: Not sure what your problem is because there isn't much information but `ListView`s `height` shouldn't be `wrap_content`. It should either be `match_parent` or a specified height

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After two weeks strugling with this problem, i was able to find a real solution,

the problem is, that the main LinearLayout was set to VERTICAL, so the texts where displaying below the imageView!

Thanks to everyone that had helped!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with the custom `ArrayAdapter`.

By observing your code, you're including tab and listview in the same fragment, right?
Don't include tab and listview in one.

Modify your code `banksTab.setContent(R.id.Banks);` to `banksTab.setContent(new Intent(this, activityClass));`.

Do your listview logic in activity class.